# create a polygon with segment and another polygon

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, geometry

I want to create a new polygon, given an initial polygon and a line segment as follow:

[image]

In the image above, I have a red polygon(initial one) (Q-B-D-F-G-...-P-Q) and a line segment(specified by green) (A - H), now my question is how I can create a polygon using this polygon and this segment line such that **starts by A, goes to H and continue by I-J-...-P-Q and ends by A**.

Note: The solution not be neither (A-B-C-A), neither (C-D-E-C) or (E-F-G-H-E)

For make it more clear, suppose we cut from the segment every thing which is outside the red polygon, and after that we fill the area created by this segment (like A-B-C-A  and E-F-G-H-E).

Any Idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A-point lies on the segment Q-B, H-point - on the segment G-I. So it seems you just have to exclude vertices between Q and B from the list, and replace them with A, H

Q-B-D-F-G-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q

Q-**A**-*B-D-F-G*-**H**-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q

Q-A-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the problem is how you know you have to start like that, I mean if you start from H and continue, you will arrive at A and you will remove all the vertices between H and A

Comment: I think that problem is not fully described, and you have to elaborate some criteria - for example, should the new polygon be simple etc. What's the origin of this problem?

Comment: I added some thing at the end of the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a lot of doubtful cases - for example, result for segment A-P is triangle AQP or another big part? And result for segment E-middle of O-N is very ambiguous. So, I think, it is not enough to have simple speculative rules